# Error importing package in Java

Tags: java, import, package

I am trying to sort my classes into packages but i can't import them.

My files are in the following folders:
 - .java files are in C:\Java\Code\src\my\app\Timer
 - .class files are in C:\Java\Code\compiled\my\app\Timer

In my class (timer) i've added `package my.app;`

Also, I have setted the CLASSPATH to look in both `src` and `compiled` folders.

Then, I have another folder where I put my "bigger" projects in:
 - C:\Java\Projects\myProject

The problem is that when I try to import the class `Timer` into `MyProject`  using `import my.app.*;`  all I get is:

> Error: package my.app does not exist

Culd you please give me a hand?

PS. My IDE is Dr.Java

Comment: There is no point in setting the CLASSPATH to look in your `src` folder. There are no .class files there, or there shouldn't be. Your CLASSPATH *when compiling your 'bigger' projects* needs to include `C:/Java/Code/compiled`.

Comment: @EJP I know but I did it anyway out of desperation because i didn't know what else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

It appears that Dr.Java ignores complitely the CLASSPATH variable. It is necessary to set in preferences where are the .class files.